# Curious results with t statistic with GARCH errors in a linear regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, least-squares, simulation, garch

So, I was playing around with an odd specification in a simulation experiment:
\begin{align}
   y_t &= x_t \beta + \sqrt{h_t} \epsilon_t \\
   h_t &= \sigma^2 + \pi \left( h_{t-1} - \sigma^2 \right) + \alpha h_{t-1} \left( \epsilon_{t-1}^2 - 1 - 2 \gamma \epsilon_{t-1} \right)
\end{align}
where $\epsilon_t \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$ and $x_{t} \overset{iid}{\sim} N(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$.

I simulated the model with $\pi = 0.9, \sigma = 2, \alpha = 0.2, \gamma = 1, \mu_x = 1, \sigma_x = 2$ and $\beta = 0$. In each Monte Carlo draw, I estimated the model while including a constant by OLS after which I tested for $\beta = 0$ using a $t$ statistic, specifically
\begin{align}
   (\hat{\mu}_y, \hat{\beta})' &:= (X'X)^{-1} X'y \\
   u_t &:= y_t - \hat{\mu}_y - \hat{\beta} x_t \\
   s^2 &:= \frac{\hat{u}' \hat{u}}{N-2} \\
   t &:= \frac{\hat{\beta} - 0}{\sqrt{ s^2 (X'X)^{-1} }}.
\end{align}
Note that I stacked observations as rows and variables as columns in $u$ and $X$. Then I proceeded as if $u_t \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, E(u_t^2))$ which is to say that I used $t | X \sim T(N-2)$ where $T$ is the Student distribution to conduct bilateral tests at levels of 10, 5 and 1%. Note that the $|$ just means I condition on $X$. Across 10 000 Monte Carlo draws, I hit almost perfectly the nominal significance levels for 150 observations. But here's the catch: it works with 15 and even 5 observations, so I strongly suspect this actually is the exact distribution of the test statistic. (To be clear, I initialize $h_t$ at its expected value of $\sigma^2$ and burn 50 periods to randomize initial values. Given the geometric decay here, 0.9 is 0.0052 after 50 periods, so that should be more than enough.)

**A Few Notes on the OLS Assumptions**
I know that some small sample assumptions are satisfied here. Obviously, the model is linear and the matrix $X$ is of full column rank. By construction, $x_t$ and $u_t$ are actually independent, so they also satisfy $E(\epsilon | X) = 0$ and my estimator is definitely unbiased. Oddly enough, the assumption of conditional homoskedasticity is also satisfied here:
\begin{align}
   E( u_t^2 | X) &= E( h_t \epsilon_t^2 | X ) \\
                 &= E( h_t | X ) E(\epsilon_t^2 | X) \\
                 &= E( h_t ) E(\epsilon_t^2 ) \\
                 &= \sigma^2
\end{align}
The first line is true by the definition of the DGP. The second line exploits the idd nature of $\epsilon_t$ to claim it is independant from $h_t$. The third line notes that $x_t$ is independant from both $h_t$ and $\epsilon_t$ so that conditioning on it adds no information. The final line used the unit variance of $\epsilon_t$ and the second equation of the DGP. So, while out compound error term $u_t = \sqrt{h_t}\epsilon_t$ is heteroskedastic with respect to the natural filtration of the whole process (i.e., E_t(u_t^2) changes over time), it is homoskedastic with respect to the filtration of $x_t$. We then have that $Var( (\hat{\mu}_y, \hat{\beta})' | X) = \sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}$ is the variance of our OLS estimator.

The last detail we need to establish to show that $t$ follows a Student distribution exactly is for $u$ to be jointly distributed as an elliptically symmetric distribution. In a typical econometrics textbook, we'd use a normal law $u \sim N(0, \sigma^2 I_N)$ (which is patently false here because of transition dynamics in $h_t$), but it can be broadened to any elliptically symmetric distribution (provided the moments I took above exists). **Why does my test statistic seem to have exactly the right distribution?** I fail to see how you'd get very tight results on levels for 5, 15 and 150 observations alike. Is there some odd reason why, by some chance, $u_t$ does happen to fall in the right class of distribution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It might just be an odd case, but I did play around with some of the parameters and it doesn't go away. The behavior seems too consistent across sample sizes for me to think it's the asymptotics kicking in favourably early.